# Entrys aren't being saved to my database correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

Here's my schema file..

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120505115340) do

  create_table "clients", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "detail"
    t.string   "more_detail"
    t.string   "more_details"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end

  create_table "jobs", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "number"
    t.string   "responsible"
    t.string   "monthly"
    t.string   "quarterly"
    t.string   "other"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

end
```

And here's my migration file's..

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :detail
      t.string :more_detail
      t.string :more_details
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :number
      t.string :responsible
      t.string :monthly
      t.string :quarterly
      t.string :other
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my view file, I have it setup so that is pulls out the `client.name` and shows it to the user `<%= link_to client.name, client_path(client) %>`.

However, all im getting back when I create a new entry is `/clients/1` instead of the name that I specified in my form.

When I try to migrate the DB nothing happens and then when I try to drop he DB to start afresh it tells me that it does even exist.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are concerned that your view displays a link to `/clients/1` for your newly created object?

This is the default path when using Ruby on Rails, and is what will be produced by the path helper object_path(object) that you are using. This can be customized (see guides on [routes.rb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)). If this is not a problem, then your application is working as intended.

BtW, the number used in the default path refers to the `id` given to the object. All objects stored using ActiveRecord will automatically get a unique `id` which can be used to identify the object. Just as the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns in your schema, the `id` column will be created regardless if you explicitly define it in your schema or not.

To reset your database (drop, recreate and migrate to current schema), use the following command:

```
rake db:reset
```

EDIT:

```
<%= link_to client.name, client_path(client) %>
```

Should result in the following HTML (where CLIENT_NAME is the name attribute of the client)

```
<a href="/clients/1">CLIENT_NAME</a>
```

Comment: But the attribute im calling in my view is not the id.

This was working before I attempted to migrate the DB to aadd the jobs table.

Comment: So.. in my form im saving the :name attribute. Why is it only showing me the client id? It was showing the client name before and as I said. I haven't touched my code except trying to migrate the db with a new model.

Ive put my code up on GitHub if the helps => https://github.com/keva161/document_manager

I believe it is a database related issue as when I navigate to the /clients/ directory and add a new client and hit save. The form will enter but there will no information saved.